# how to assign values of the column for given conditional statements

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

I need a script to assign values of the column with a given conditional argument. To be specific, here is my data and my condition

input `data.file`:

```
0.4
3.6
-2.4
0.1
-2.0
1.6
2.2
3.6
```

condition: assign R if data.file greater than 2(>2), assign S if data.file less than -2(<-2), and assign M if data.file greater than or equal to-2 and less than or equal to 2 [-2,2].

Desired output file `out.file`

```
0.4  M
3.6  R
-2.4 S
0.1  M
-2.0 M
1.6  M
2.2  R
3.6  R
```

Comment: so what's the problem? have you tried anything? [so] might be a good place to ask programming specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

read your file line by line, check whether the value falls into a given category and output accordingly.

```
 awk '{if($1>2)print $1,"R"; else if ($1<-2)print $1,"S"; else print $1,"M"}'
```